# Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.5.v20170502:run (default-cli) on project Myproject Failure

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jetty

I tried to run my project on Zookeeper & Intellij with maven helper plugin and click on jetty:run. But it give me an error

**Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven plugin:9.4.5.v20170502:run (default-cli) on project Myproject Failure**

I tried to invalidate cache, check the jdk version, and search it on many forum but doesn't get any clue. Is anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Is it possible to run this goal from command line?

Comment: @y.bedrov yeah, i run it with command line too, and give the same error

Comment: Post the full log.

Comment: Include the full logs, and also consider upgrading your version of Jetty, as 9.4.5 is about 40 releases behind in the 9.4.x series now.